# If a table is dropped from pg_class accidentally then how to restore it from backup?

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, database-restore

I accidentally dropped a table from `pg_class` and I have the same table present in a different server inside a schema. How do I restore it?

I have tried this

```
psql -U {user-name} -d {desintation_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}`
```

This is what i'm getting -

```
ERROR:  type "food_ingredients" already exists`
HINT:  A relation has an associated type of the same name, so you must use a name that doesn't conflict with any existing type.`
ERROR:  relation "food_ingredients" does not exist`
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "19411"`
LINE 1: 19411 10405 2074 45.3333333333 0.17550085492131515 NULL NULL...`
ERROR:  relation "food_ingredients" does not exist`
```

`food_ingredients` is the table which I dropped from the pg_class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you get from messing with system catalogs.

The simple and correct answer is “restore from a backup”, but something tells me that that's not the answer you were looking for.

You could drop the type that belongs to the table, all indexes on the table, all constraints, toast tables and so on, but you'd probably forget to drop something or drop something you shouldn't and end up with a bigger mess than before.
Moreover, the table file would be left behind and it would be hard to identify and delete it.

It would be appealing to try and recreate the `pg_class` row that you dropped, but you wouldn't be able to create it with the correct `oid` since you cannot directly insert a certain `oid` or update that column.

You could dump the whole database cluster with `pg_dumpall`, create a new cluster with `initdb` and restore the backup there, but this might fail because of the data inconsistencies.

Really, the best thing is to restore a backup.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! I deleted the whole database and restored the backup. Nothing else was working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform a **partial restore** using the [**pg_dirtyread**](https://github.com/omniti-labs/pgtreats/tree/master/contrib/pg_dirtyread) extension.

Initial situation was:

```
relation "messed_table" does not exist`
```

The following query provided me the values I had dropped:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_dirtyread('pg_class'::regclass)
as t(relname name, relnamespace oid, reltype oid, reloftype oid, relowner oid, relam oid, relfilenode oid, reltablespace oid, relpages integer, reltuples real, relallvisible integer, reltoastrelid oid, relhasindex boolean, relisshared boolean, relpersistence "char", relkind "char", relnatts smallint, relchecks smallint, relhasoids boolean, relhaspkey boolean, relhasrules boolean, relhastriggers boolean, relhassubclass boolean, relrowsecurity boolean, relforcerowsecurity boolean, relispopulated boolean, relreplident "char", relispartition boolean, relfrozenxid xid, relminmxid xid, relacl aclitem[], reloptions text[], relpartbound pg_node_tree)
WHERE relname = 'messed_table';
```

I used the result for performing an INSERT:

```sql
INSERT INTO pg_class
(relname,relnamespace,reltype,reloftype,relowner,relam,relfilenode,reltablespace,relpages,reltuples,relallvisible,reltoastrelid,relhasindex,relisshared,relpersistence,relkind,relnatts,relchecks,relhasoids,relhaspkey,relhasrules,relhastriggers,relhassubclass,relrowsecurity,relforcerowsecurity,relispopulated,relreplident,relispartition,relfrozenxid,relminmxid,relacl,reloptions,relpartbound)
VALUES('messed_table',16447,17863,0,10,0,17861,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,'p','r',78,0,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,'d',false,1129231::text::xid,1::text::xid,null,null,null);
```

At this stage executing a `SELECT * from messed_table` returned

```
catalog is missing 78 attribute(s) for relid 26130
```

So I created a new table `messed_table_copy` having the same structure of the messed table.

I exported to a file the `pg_attribute` content for the `messed_table_copy` table using this query:

```sql
Copy (SELECT * FROM pg_attribute WHERE attrelid = (SELECT oid from pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 'messed_table_copy') and attnum > 0) To '/tmp/recover.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

I changed the `attrelid` value to the `relid` value pointed out in the error message and I imported the data from the file again:

```sql
COPY pg_attribute(attrelid,attname,atttypid,attstattarget,attlen,attnum,attndims,attcacheoff,atttypmod,attbyval,attstorage,attalign,attnotnull,atthasdef,attidentity,attisdropped,attislocal,attinhcount,attcollation,attacl,attoptions,attfdwoptions) FROM '/tmp/recover.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

At this stage `SELECT count(*) FROM messed_table` worked but a `SELECT * FROM messed_table` crashed the database with the following error:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

Performing some queries specifying only a subset of all the available columns I noticed that only selecting certain columns a crash happened. I had been able to recover about 90% of the data, losing the content of some columns. Good luck and remember to never play with the `pg_class` table again.